# Gitlab CE and Operator runner API

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, openshift

I have installed gitlab (v14.X) Operator runner on `OpenShift` (v4.6). The Runner successfully registered with GitLab for a specific project. The Log has following error

```
[0;33mWARNING: Checking for jobs... failed              [0;m  [0;33mrunner[0;m=6n8GmA23 [0;33mstatus[0;m=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlabce.apps.dit-ocp.companydomain.net/api/v4/jobs/request: Post https://gitlabce.apps.dit-ocp.companydomain.net/api/v4/jobs/request: EO
```

The project is with public permission and no connection issue (FW) between Gitlab and Runner. Runner token are able to list projects(verified through postman and runner terminal). Triggered a Pipeline in GitLab, but runner is not able to pick the job.

Any help is really appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some reading and with experiment I figured it out that it should be some setting issue. After editing the runner config and set "Can run untagged jobs" to Yes, the jobs started running.

I thought it will help others who are in similar situation.